# can I store a react component to a state? so I can load it dynamically

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I'm new to react. I think it's a dumb question.
can I do something like this:

```
this.setState({componentToLoad : MyComponent})
```

or is there any "react way" to load component dynamically

similar to jquery code:

```
$(".container").load(url)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess is right. You do not want to put components in state. The "react way" to load a component dynamically is to conditionally render a component based on state. For example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Foo extends Component {
  state = {
    bar: false,
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.bar 
          ? <p>True, bar.</p>
          : <p>Ain't so, bar.</p>
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Here's the docs on it:
https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: thanks for answering, so if I do conditional rendering for form, i need to import all the form component first? I have 10 different form :(

Comment: If you want to do conditional rendering like I laid out there. You might want to look at React.lazy and lazy loading:
https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html
https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-use-react-lazy-and-suspense-for-components-lazy-loading-8d420ecac58

Comment: if your component doesn't "know about" (import) all of your form components, it can receive a component as a prop, and the parent of this component may import all the forms, and pass is to your component

Comment: Sure thing @Necrofantaisie!

Answer (score 0):

use React Lazy for code splitting your components https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html